# How to push files into Enhanced FTP instead of Safehouse using Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, sftp

I have written using automation studio where sql query and data extract activity that successfully ran and is tied to the dataextension that is defined as part of data extract activity. In the third step using File Transfer activity, I select the Option "Move a file from safehouse" . THis step also runs

THE requirement from my customer is to use only Enhanced FTP and not Safehouse as they want to audit all pushes from a particular folder in Salesforce Enhanced FTP.

### Question is

I need help on extracting data from Safehouse (which shows green in automation studio) where the generated file needs to move into Salesforce ENhaned FTP. Also I am unable to check the files that is there in safehouse ftp

OR
Let me know how to use automation studio where without using Safehouse , if I can push to a particular folder in Salesforce Enhanced FTP , post creation of dataextension with records.

Thanks and Regards
Rajesh Natarjan

Comment: As far as I know you cant go around the safehouse concept that sfmc uses.

Answer (score 3):

Safehouse is indeed the only way you can extract data from SFMC, before it hits the destination file location with File Transfer activity. It is a Salesforce Marketing Cloud secure file transfer location where you can import or transfer decrypted and zipped files into or out of the Marketing Cloud without them being exposed in the Enhanced FTP Site Import directory. The system retains data in Safehouse for up to 21 days. There is no way of bypassing it.

I don't see, however, how your client will benefit in terms of the requirement provided by bypassing the Safehouse?

Comment: We were in the process of an implementation of a process where we planned to use custom file retention periods to clear exported "backup" files. This doesn't work after the January release and there is no more platform based way to automatically delete files after a set period of time. Do the files in safehouse get deleted after 21 days for sure? Extracting them to the safehouse and only exporting them to the FTP when really required would at least come close to it and might satisfy the customer...

Comment: @StephandePaly - you can request Salesforce support to enable a data extract, which can delete a file instead of moving it. Should work for your use case

Comment: We have that in another account. As far as I remember wildcards don't allow rolling ranges (at least not that I know of). So we can't selectively delete files with a certain age. Gotta check tomorrow to be sure, though

Comment: "Do the files in safehouse get deleted after 21 days for sure?" - Yes and No, persistence of files is guaranteed for 21 days after this period Salesforce could be delete them without any alert. It means that files in FTP could be stored for more then 21 days.

Comment: @Frogmouth this refers to the FTP. I'm wondering how it works for the safehouse. I can imagine that salesforce keeps the retention there and deletes files because you certainly can't do it by yourself.

Comment: @StephandePaly, Safehouse is a specific location in the MC SFTP not accessible using a Marketing Cloud FTP user. Take a look on this note of Jen release notes:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2020_platform_ftp_retention.htm&type=5
It mention FTP without using the term "Safehouse" or "Enhanced FTP" so should be valid for both.